# Am I using viewModels correctly (MVC4)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an object that I would like to display in a Details view.  The object has a bunch of properties that the view needs.

The object also has parents and grandparents, which I need to display in the view.

What I have for my object viewModel is:

```
public class ObjectViewModel
{
    // Used when creating a new object under a parent object
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int? ParentObjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Object Object { get; set; }

    // Info that only the view needs, which is defined in the Controller based on some logic
    public string ActiveTitle { get; set; }

    // A bre
    public IList<Object> ParentObjects { get; set; } 
}
```

I then use this in my Detail controller method:

```
public ActionResult Detail(int objectId)
{

    // TODO: Make this a service call
    var object = _db.Objects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ObjectId == objectId);

    if (object == null)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }

    var model = new SetViewModel() { 
         ActiveTitle = object.Name, 
         Object = object, 
         ParentObjectId = object.ParentObject.ObjectId, 
         ParentObjects = _objectService.GetParentObjects(set.ParentObject)
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Does this look right?  Or should I be pulling the required **fields** from the Object model into the viewModel, and not the **objects** themselves?

Comment: Firstly, I don't think this is a good question for SO. Secondly, you pull as much data as you need. Using whole objects are fine, if you don't use all the properties then *you* decide if that's an acceptable performance hit or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have an object type in your view model is super vague and your code would be hard to support if you are not the original programmer. I would Add the class type to the actual model or use generics to specify the class type as shown below:

```
public class ObjectViewModel<T>
{
    // Used when creating a new object under a parent object
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int? ParentObjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public T Object { get; set; }

    // Info that only the view needs, which is defined in the Controller based on some logic
    public string ActiveTitle { get; set; }

    // A bre
    public IList<T> ParentObjects { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either option will work, and you will often have a mixture of both techniques in a given application.

The key idea is that your view model should contain *what the view needs* in order to display the data to the user.

If your view merely displays the individual, primitive fields in simply controls, e.g. a series of labels or textbox controls, then your view model should probably specify only the fields, and not the parent object.

However, it's very possible for your view to include a templated or custom control that "knows how" to display a complex object in its entirety. In that case, your view model would need to include the entire object. (In practice I find myself doing this much more often in WPF than ASP-MVC but I've done both).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer will be contextual.  Many teams using layered architectures might adopt architectural conventions whereby layers below X should not be referenced directly by your views, and a data access class might be a likely candidate for such a restriction.  In your case, it does look like you will be binding your view's structure to the structure directly to your database schema (assuming, since you're using "_db"), which might be considered unreasonably tight coupling.

Also, I'm assuming you're using "object" to represent "any general thing" rather than literally a System.Object, since your objects appear to have an ObjectId property in your lambda expression.